# I have two dictionaries within one dictionary and cannot figure out how to access a specific value

Tags: python, html, django

I tried looking at other examples but none of them helped me, 
My problem is somewhere in either constant or views,  I cannot seem to grab the value  of header from landing page from CONSTANTS.PY. Please help me figure out how what i'm calling in VIEWS.PY is wrong.

CONSTANTS.PY

```
videos = {'landing_page': {
    'header': 'What\'s it like to take a class at ?',
    'subheader': ' \"There are students who keep in touch for years after they\'ve taken a language class here.\" Learn more about the   experience and what it means to learn a language with us in the video below. You\'re not just taking a class; you\'re getting an immersive experience and joining a growing community',
    'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/'},
      'private_lesson': {
    'header': 'SEE WHAT A CLASS LOOKS LIKE AND MEET OUR TEACHERS',
    'subheader': ' \"There are students who keep in touch for years after they\'ve taken a language class here.\" Learn more about the  experience and what it means to learn a language with us in the video below. You\'re not just taking a class; you\'re getting an immersive experience and joining a growing community',
    'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/'}}
```

VIEWS.PY

```
@render_to('video-section.html')
def video_section(request):
context = {}
context['headerLP'] = c.videos['landing_page']['header']
return context
```

HTMLFILE

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<section class="video-section">
  <div class="padded-center-container">
    <h2>{{ headerLP }}</h2>
    <p>"There are students who keep in touch for years after they've 
taken a language class here." Learn more about the he video 
below. You're not just taking a class; you're getting an immersive 
experience and joining a growing community.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="video-wrapper">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Python dictionary keys cannot be mutable, so using a list in `get([{'subheader'}])` does not make sense. Perhaps you want `c.videos['landing_page']['subheader']` or `c.videos['landing_page'].get('subheader')` if you need to handle the case when the key does not exist.

Comment: have you tried to print `c.videos` from `video_section()` ? To check if it looks like the example you give us.

Comment: To be clear, its the header that is causing problems, forget the subheader. I tried both `c.videos['landing_page']['header']` and `c.videos['landing_page'].get('subheader')` but i kept getting bad template variable

Comment: How are you importing the videos dictionary from constants.py file to views.py?? What is c?? How can you access c.videos??

Comment: from . import constants as c